# Reading a .NET Stream : high CPU usage - how to read wihtout while (true)?

Tags: android, .net, bluetooth, stream, xamarin

Since my problem is close to this one, I haven been looing at feedbacks from this possible solution : [Reading on a NetworkStream = 100% CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910378/reading-on-a-networkstream-100-cpu-usage) but I fail to find the solution I need.

Much like in this other question, I want to use something else than an infinite while loop.

More precisely, I am using `Xamarin` to build `Android` application in `Visual Studio`. Since I need a `Bluetooth` service I am using a `Stream` to read and send data.

Reading data from `Stream.InputStrem` is where I have a problem : is there some sort of **a blocking call to wait for data to be available** without using a while (true) loop ?

I tried :

- Begin/End Read
- Task.Run and await

Here is a code sample:

```
public byte[] RetrieveDataFromStream()
    {
        List<byte> packet = new List<byte>();
        int readBytes = 0;
        while (_inputStream.CanRead && _inputStream.IsDataAvailable() && readBytes < 1024 && _state == STATE_CONNECTED)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
                readBytes = _inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                packet.Add(buffer[0]);
            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return packet.ToArray();
    }
```

I call this method from a while loop.
This loop will check until this method returns something else than NULL in which case I will process the data accordingly.

As soon as there is data to be processed, the CPU usage gets low, way lower than if there was no data to process.

I know why my CPU usage is high : the loop will check as often as possible if there is something to read. On the plus side, there is close to no delay when recieving data, but no, that's not a viable solution.

Any ideas to change this ?

**# UPDATE 1**

As per Marc Gravell's idea, here is what I would like to understand and try :

```
byte buffer = new byte[4096];
while (_inputStream.CanRead
  && (readBytes = _inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0
  && _state == STATE_CONNECTED)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < readBytes; i++)
        packet.Add(buffer[i]);
    // or better: some kind of packet.AddRange(buffer, 0, readBytes)
}
```

How do you call this code snippet ?
Two questions :

1. If there is nothing to read, then the while condition will be
   dismissed : what to do next ?
2. Once you're done reading, what do you do next ? What do you do to catch any new incoming packets ?

Here are some explanations that should help :

1. The android device is connected, via bluetooth, to another device that sends data. It will always send a pre-designed packet with a specified size (1024)
2. That device can stream the data continuously for some time but can also stop at any time for a long period too. How to deal with such behavior ?

Comment: The main problem there looks to be the "hot loop" when `IsDataAvailable()` returns `false`. Frankly, you *don't need that check* - just `Read`

Comment: Thank you. I will take it into consideration. If it doesn't "break" my algorithm and creates a smaller CPU load :)

Answer (score 1):

An immediate fix would be:

- don't read one byte at a time
- don't create a new buffer per-byte
- don't sit in a hot loop when there is no data available

For example:

```
byte buffer = new byte[4096];
while (_inputStream.CanRead
  && (readBytes = _inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0
  && _state == STATE_CONNECTED)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < readBytes; i++)
        packet.Add(buffer[i]);
    // or better: some kind of packet.AddRange(buffer, 0, readBytes)
}
```

Note that the use of `readBytes` in the original `while` check looked somewhat... confused; I've replaced it with a "while we don't get an EOF" check; feel free to add your own logic.

Comment: Alright, I've seen this pattern a few times, but ... where and how do you call it ? I'll update my post to be more precised. Thanks